# Why can I set properties during instantiation through __init__, but not through another method?

Tags: python, function, class

This is working

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,ka,sif):
        self.ka = ka
        self.sif = sif
    def b(self):
        pass

c = a("d","e")
c
print(c.ka,c.sif)
```

but

This is not working

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def b(self,ka,sif):
        self.ka = ka
        self.sif = sif

c = a().b("d","e")
c
print(c.ka,c.sif)
```

Why?

I expected the get same result. Why these are not have same results.

Comment: `b` doesn't return anything.

Comment: But the first one is too not return anything? I am new sorry

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].

Comment: the constructor automatically returns `self`. methods do not, unless you explicitly do so.

Comment: Try to avoid using "this" in question titles in a way that leaves it vague what "this" is. The goal of a good title is to let someone who has the same problem, years later, find your question in search results and learn from its answers. What are the changes that someone else will have the same values of "this", and that even if they do, they'll know that from the title enough to click through and read the body when it shows up in search results?

Comment: `b` sets the attributes just fine. The problem is that `c` is not the object you think it is.

Comment: Technically, `a` is not a direct call to `a.__init__`. `a` is an instance of `type`, so `a()` is equivalent to `type.__call__(a)`. The definition of `type.__call__`  uses `a.__new__` to get a new object. If that object has type `a`, then that object's `__init__` method is called before the object itself is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a("d","e")` will call `__init__` and return the new instance of the class `a`. Regular methods do not have this behavior.

The `b` method does not return anything (so it implicitly returns `None`); if you want to be able to chain that method, add `return self` at the end.

Comment: Nitpick/clarification: while _here_ `a("d","e")` does behave so, constructors in general do not have to (if you `def __new__(cls): return 2`, `a("d","e")` will return `2`, and not an instance of `a`. (Of course, this is to be used extremely sparingly).

Comment: @Amadan Returning anything other than `None` from `__init__` is a runtime error if `__init__` is invoked through the usual implicit manner.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, brainfart, I meant `__new__`.

Answer (score 0):

To be even more explicit about how to fix this:

```
c = a()
c.b("d", "e")
print(c.ka, c.sif)
```

Now we're not depending on `b` to return anything (which it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an instance of `type`. Like any other class, an instance of `type` is callable because `type.__call__` is defined, so `a()` is equivalent to `type.__call__(a)`.

You can imagine the definition of `__call__` looks something like this, if it were written in pure Python:

```
class type:

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.__new__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(obj, self):
            obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj
```

If you were to unwrap this, a call like

```
c = a()
```

is like the following code:

```
c = a.__new__()
if isinstance(c, a):
    c.__init__()
```

So, you should be able to see that

```
c = a()
c.b(...)
```

is quite different from

```
c = a().b(...)
```

in terms of what is actually assigned to the name `c`. In the latter case, you *lose* the reference to the new instance of `a` once its `b` method completes.